# R dplyr aggregate count or amount within time interval in mins

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which consist of date_time, account (both are character) and amount (numeric) as below:

```
sample data:
    date_time <- as.character(c('2018-01-22 18:18:00','2018-01-22 18:18:05','2018-01-22 18:18:19','2018-01-22 18:18:00','2018-01-22 18:30:12','2018-01-22 18:18:11'))
    account <- as.character(c('a0001','a0001','a0001','b0001','b0001','c0001'))
    amount <- c(1000,200,300,10000,400,10000)
    df.sample <- data.frame(date_time, account, amount)
```

I would like to return TRUE if for transaction such that aggregate count >= 2 AND aggregate amount >= 12000 within 1 mins for each account, FALSE otherwise.

I wrote a function using dplyr as below:

```
simulation <- function(df, v.acct, v.date.time) {

  # v.acct <- '5408044133161021'
  # v.date.time <- as.POSIXct('2018-01-22 18:18:11')
  #time.interval <- 120

  #subset
  df2 <- df %>% 
          mutate(date.time=as.POSIXct(date_time),
                 diff.time=difftime(v.date.time, date.time, units=c('mins'))) %>%
          filter(account %in% v.acct,  diff.time <= time.interval, diff.time > 0) 

  df.summary <- df2 %>% 
                  group_by(account) %>%
                  summarise(agg.cnt=n(),
                            agg.amt=sum(amount))

  nrow <- df.summary %>% filter(agg.cnt>=agg.count, agg.amt>=agg.amount) %>% nrow()

  result <- ifelse(nrow==0, FALSE, TRUE)

  return(result)

}
```

And vector will be return which contain TRUE or FALSE :

```
time.interval <- 10
agg.count <- 10
agg.amount <- 20000
v.result <- apply(df[,c(1,2)],1,function(x) simulation(x[2],x[1]))
```

Issue:
Above code able to return the result, while if the dataset become over 90,000 observation the computation time will be very long. Is there any alternative method? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that OP does not mind a `data.table` solution, you can use a non-equi self-join to find instances that falls within 1min of each transactions (`by=.EACHI` tells `data.table` to perform the join for each row of data in `i=df`. See `?data.table` to see what `i` and `.EACHI` mean).

Then check if the count is greater than or equal to `agg.count` and if total amount is greater than or equal to `agg.amount`

data:

```
date_time <- as.character(c('2018-01-22 18:18:00','2018-01-22 18:18:05','2018-01-22 18:18:19','2018-01-22 18:18:00','2018-01-22 18:30:12','2018-01-22 18:18:11'))
account <- c('a0001','a0001','a0001','b0001','b0001','c0001')
amount <- c(1000,200,300,10000,400,10000)
df <- data.frame(date_time, account, amount)

time.interval <- 60
agg.count <- 10
agg.amount <- 20000
```

code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, date_time := as.POSIXct(date_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
df[, oneMinLater := date_time + time.interval]
df[, hit :=
    df[df, 
    .N >= agg.count & sum(amount, na.rm=TRUE) >= agg.amount,
    by=.EACHI, 
    on=.(account, date_time > date_time, date_time <= oneMinLater)]$V1
]
```

output:

```
             date_time account amount         oneMinLater   hit
1: 2018-01-22 18:18:00   a0001   1000 2018-01-22 18:19:00 FALSE
2: 2018-01-22 18:18:05   a0001    200 2018-01-22 18:19:05 FALSE
3: 2018-01-22 18:18:19   a0001    300 2018-01-22 18:19:19 FALSE
4: 2018-01-22 18:18:00   b0001  10000 2018-01-22 18:19:00 FALSE
5: 2018-01-22 18:30:12   b0001    400 2018-01-22 18:31:12 FALSE
6: 2018-01-22 18:18:11   c0001  10000 2018-01-22 18:19:11 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @chinsoon12. what if i would like to name the new column V1 as hit? how can i achieve that?

Comment: or append the v.result as column in df with name "hit"

Comment: Thanks! @chinsoon first time know by=.EACHI. i always feel data.table is quite complicated compare to dplyr for readability.

Comment: there is another question such that if i would like to calculate the aggregate count and aggregate amount with the condition hit==FALSE. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean another aggregate of the above output?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a possible solution:

```
   library(data.table)
    library(lubridate)
    library(zoo)
    setDT(df)
    df[, date.time := as.POSIXct(date_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
    df[, time.diff := difftime(date.time,min(date.time), units='mins')+0.0001, by=account]
    df[, interval := ceiling(time.diff / dminutes(time.interval)), by=account]
    df[, agg.cnt:=seq_len(.N), by=.(account, interval)]
    df[, agg.amt2:=cumsum(amount), by=.(account, interval)]
```